# CiviReport widgets show access denied on CiviCRM Dashboard

Tags: civireport, dashlet

I've recently migrated a site to another host and pretty much everything is working except that when I go to /civicrm, the dashlets on the dashboard all show Access Denied and a login form.  They are being provided by CiviReport according to their respective breadcrumbs.

In addition, I noticed that I could not disable CiviReport or any of the other CiviCRM Components.  When I click Save on that page, it just bumps me back to /civicrm/admin with no error message.  Going back into civicrm/admin/setting/component just shows the modules still enabled.

I'm still a CiviCRM noob, so it could be something simple.

Comment: Check your civicrm.settings.php file. I suspect your baseurl is incorrect.  What CMS are you using?    Also read through this https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC42/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location

Comment: ... or the latest version at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/

Comment: Tommy B > I've double-checked my base URL and I can see the data in CiviCRM.  The CMS in this case is Drupal.  I'm also having the same problem on a different site with Wordpress, too, though.

I followed the same steps as in that guide, but I didn't actually disable CiviCRM before dumping the DB.  Do you think that could cause it?

Answer (score 3):

Check your `civicrm.settings.php`, and make sure that the `CIVICRM_BASE_URL` matches your site url.

My site was redirecting `http://domain.com` to `http://www.domain.com`, but `civicrm.settings.php` had the version without the `www`, which was screwing things up.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are using `https://...` or `http://...` consistently and not mixing them. (Preferably `https`!)

I have seen that where you have a mismatch between the URL you are logging in with and the resource URL's (configured at `Administer > System Settings > Resource URL's`).  For example, if your Resource URL's are `https://...` but you log in as `http://`

I usually redirect any `http://...` requests to `https://...` in `.htaccess`

Comment: I do have redirection set up and the content in the widgets are being addressed by https.
Also, I have the resource URLs set and they look right to me.  Are they supposed to be in the format: https://www.domain.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm ?

Comment: That was the right format, except that it should include `https://` at the front.  Newer installations use `[civicrm.root]`. If you go to `Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs` then click the help icon at the end of the help box then it will show you the values in use on your site.

Comment: Also, you could open the Network tab in your browser to confirm the URLs being requested.  Eg for Firefox, go to `Tools > Web Developer > Network` and reload your dashboard.